# Google plus login requires permission on every login

Tags: google-plus, google-signin

I have implemented a Facebook, Twitter and Google plus login to my website. For Facebook and Twitter the user needs to give permission to the app one time, unless i make a change in the required information.

Google Plus however asks for permission for my app every single time. And I can not find anywhere to configure the app in only requesting this once.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for your button?  Specifically, are you using the `approval_prompt=force` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the 'approvalprompt' to 'auto'

```
function render() {
 gapi.signin.render('customBtn', {
  //'callback': 'signinCallback',
  'clientid': '841077041629.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
  'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
  'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
  'approvalprompt': 'auto'
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `approvalprompt` parameter from your sign-in code. I assume you copied from one of the examples that uses this parameter to ensure that the example is always in a new state.